# Amazon RDS for Oracle - archive_lag_target db parameter

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Can we change `archive_lag_target` DB parameter value to `1800` in RDS?

I see only allowed values (60,120,180,240,300). Is there any other way to achieve this in Amazon RDS for Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

No, it appears that `60, 120, 180, 240, 300` are the only permitted values.

I tried it via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
$ aws rds  modify-db-parameter-group --db-parameter-group-name oracle --parameters ParameterName=archive_lag_target,ParameterValue=1800
```

The response was:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the ModifyDBParameterGroup operation: Value: 1800 is outside of range: 60,120,180,240,300 for parameter: archive_lag_target

From [ARCHIVE_LAG_TARGET Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams009.htm#REFRN10003):

> **ARCHIVE_LAG_TARGET** limits the amount of data that can be lost and effectively increases the availability of the standby database by forcing a log switch after the specified amount of time elapses.
>
> A 0 value disables the time-based thread advance feature; otherwise, the value represents the number of seconds. Values larger than 7200 seconds are not of much use in maintaining a reasonable lag in the standby database. **The typical, or recommended value is 1800 (30 minutes).** Extremely low values can result in frequent log switches, which could degrade performance; such values can also make the archiver process too busy to archive the continuously generated logs.

So, it appears that Amazon RDS is **forcing a maximum of 5 minutes lag**.